# weighted graph implement using js

Tags: javascript

I created this graph and am trying to make it wieghted directed graph

```
   class Graph{
    #nodes;
    constructor(){
        this.#nodes={}
    }
    addNode(node){
        this.#nodes[node]=[]
    }


    addEdge(source,vertix){
        if( ! this.#nodes[source] || ! this.#nodes[vertix]){
            return false
        }
        // this.vertix[destination]=distancex
        if(! this.#nodes[source].includes(vertix)){
            this.#nodes[source].push(vertix)
        }
    }
    showNodes(){
      console.log(this.#nodes)
    }


}
```

and now am trying to add edges :

```
for(let i=0;i<citiesnamesarr.length;i++)
        {
                 mapgraph.addNode(citiesnamesarr[i])
                   var x={}

                var citiesform=document.getElementsByClassName(`check${citiesnamesarr[i]} `)
                var distanceform=document.getElementsByClassName(`distance${citiesnamesarr[i]} `)
                for(let j=0;j<citiesform.length;j++)
                {
                   var  edge=citiesform[j].value
                  var  distance=distanceform[j].value
                     x[edge]=distance 
                 
                 }
                 v[i]=x

                 mapgraph.addEdge(citiesnamesarr[i],v[i])

                 
         }
```

but when I print the graph it gives me an empty array :

> {city1: Array(0), city2: Array(0), city3: Array(0)}

knowing when I tried to print  the array v it works

> 0:{city2: '87', city1: ''}

> 1: {city0: '12', city1: '78'}

> 2: {city0: '', city1: '21'}

Comment: What is your `v`?

Comment: just an empty array to store the edges

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in what you're doing is that your method `addEdge` is meant to add one edge at the time, but when you're calling it in your code, you're trying to add multiple edges at the same time.

I rewrote your code for better understanding:

```
for(let cityname of citiesnamesarr){
    mapgraph.addNode(cityname);

    var adjacentVertices={};

    var cityInputArr=document.getElementsByClassName(`check${cityName} `);
    var distanceInputArr=document.getElementsByClassName(`distance${cityName} `);

    for(let key in cityInputArr){
        var destination=cityInputArr[key].value;
        var distance=distanceInputArr[key].value;
        adjacentVertices[destination]=distance; 
    }

    mapgraph.addEdge(cityname,adjacentVertices);
}
```

To solve the issues, you'd either need to call your method `addEdges` and do something like:

```
addEdges(node,edges){
    this.#nodes[node] = edges;
}
```

And call this method instead.

Or you can keep a method that adds a single edge with:

```
addEdge(source, destination, distance){
    this.#nodes[source].push([destination, distance]);
}
```

And change your code to something like:

```
for(let cityname of citiesnamesarr){
    mapgraph.addNode(cityname);

    var cityInputArr=document.getElementsByClassName(`check${cityName} `);
    var distanceInputArr=document.getElementsByClassName(`distance${cityName} `);

    for(let key in cityInputArr){
        var destination=cityInputArr[key].value;
        var distance=distanceInputArr[key].value;

        mapgraph.addEdge(cityname,destination, distance); 
    }
}
```

Note that a weighed graph has a more complex structure that an unweighed graph.
An unweighed graph can be represented as an adjacency list:

0: [1, 4, 6]

1: [0, 3, 4]

etc.

While for a weighed graph needs to store an additional value:

0: [[1, 300], [4, 250], [6, -20]]

1: [[0, 100], [3, 76], [4, -10]]

etc.

Depending on which algorithms you'd like to use, a matrix might be more convenient.